# How to use new line command while using multicolumn in tabular?

Tags: tables, macros

I am trying to use the new line command within the multicolumn command in tabular. When I use it messes up the table in the following way. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{tabular}{l|*{8}{c}r}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Aug. D-F Z(t)-stat} & \multicolumn{2{c}{P-P Z(t)-stat.}\\
    \hline
    Team & Un-Differenced & Differenced & Un-Differenced & Differenced   \\
    \hline
    K-12 Education                  & 2 & 4 & 2 & 4    \\
    Medicaid and Welfare            & 6 & 3 & 2 & 4   \\
    Public Health and Hospitals     & 6 & 2 & 2 & 4   \\
    Natural Resources               & 6 & 2 & 2 & 4   \\
    Higher Education                & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4   \\
    Highways                        & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4   \\
    Police and Prisons              & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4   \\
    Other Spending                  & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4   \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Note: Augmented Dickey Fuller Z(t) test statistics word word wword wword word word word \\word  word.}
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: You can only use \newline in a p column (or variant).  You can also put a tabular inside a tabular column.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

With `talltblr` defined by the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Overview of statistic. Diff.: Differened},
remark{Note} = {Augmented Dickey Fuller Z(t) test statistics word word word word word word word word  word.}
                ]{colspec = {l| *{4}{c}}}
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Aug. D-F Z(t)-stat  
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    P-P Z(t)-stat.      
                &                                       \\
    \hline
Team & Un-Diff. & Diff. & Un-Diff. & Diff.   \\
    \hline
    K-12 Education                  & 2 & 4 & 2 & 4     \\
    Medicaid and Welfare            & 6 & 3 & 2 & 4     \\
    Public Health and Hospitals     & 6 & 2 & 2 & 4     \\
    Natural Resources               & 6 & 2 & 2 & 4     \\
    Higher Education                & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4     \\
    Highways                        & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4     \\
    Police and Prisons              & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4     \\
    Other Spending                  & 6 & 4 & 2 & 4     \\
    \hline
    \end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

- In columns type `c` (or `l`, `t`) you a text in cells can be only in one line, multiline text is possible to write only in `p{width}` (or `b` or `m`) column types. This means that in your case you should know table width.
- With use of `threeparttable` or its equivalent `talltblr` defined in the `tabullarray` package this can be simple solved by use of table notes or remarks ia is used in above MWE,
- It is not clear, why you specify 10 columns when you use only five.